# Calling a Method from a C# Dll in Excel VBA

Tags: c#, vba, excel, dll

I am attempting to use a method in VBA from a C# dll that I created. The file is COM visible and referenced in my VBA file.

Here is my VBA code:

```
Private Declare Function COMPaste Lib "C:\Blah\bin\x86\Debug\TestCOMExposure.dll" Alias "Countdown" (ByVal left As Integer) As Integer
Sub TestA()
Dim instance As TestCOMExposure.TestProgram
Set instance = New TestCOMExposure.TestProgram
MsgBox (instance.COMPaste)

End Sub
```

To see my method in C# dll:

```
namespace TestCOMExposure
{
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisible(true)]
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.ClassInterface(
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [ProgId("TestCOMExposure.TestProgram")]
    [Guid("4EFE27BF-A442-4F93-9A55-A00BD2D7160A")]
    public class TestProgram : ITestProgram
    {
        public void Countdown()
        {
            int i = 60;
            int day = 3;
            int left = i - day;
            Console.WriteLine("Saba has {0} days left", left);
            Console.Read();
        }
```

And my interface code:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("20DF3D06-0DC6-445D-9149-F23A34B0624F")]
public interface ITestProgram
{
    void Countdown();
}
```

The error that I get when I run my VBA code is" Automation Error The system cannot find the file specified. Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Did you double check the path of the DLL?

Comment: Yup, I have. I just cut it short by writing "Blah" for the sake of the post.